# Loop through text files, replace consecutive asterisks with 0.00

Tags: matlab, text, replace

all,

I am writing a matlab program to read in text data and rearrange it. Now I am meeting with a new problem.

When I am writing data out to csv file, there are randomly missing data noted as ******, as shown below causing my program to terminate.

```
2055   6  17  24.2 29.57  7.02******  0.99  2.65  2.73  4.09  0.11
```

Any one can help me with a small program to loop through all the text files in the folder, and replace the consecutive stars, with 0.00? The stars are always in columns 33 to 38, occupying 6 spaces. I want it to be changed to be two spaces followed by 0.00.

Thanks,
James

Comment: Could you specify in your question what the correct output should be? In your example, what should this line be changed to?

Comment: Thanks. All the lines are in the same format. In the example line, I want the 6 stars to be changed to two spaces followed by 0.00. They should be placed in column 35~38.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given text file, you can read it into memory, replace the asterisks with the desired text, and then overwrite the original text file:

```
filename = 'blah.txt'

% Read it into memory
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
scanned_fields = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);
% The first (and only) field of textscan will be our cell array of text
lines = scanned_fields{1};

% Replace the asterisks with the desired text
lines = strrep(lines, '******', '  0.00');

% Overwrite the original file
fid = fopen(filename, 'w');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', lines{:});
fclose(fid);
```

To do this for all of the text files in your directory, you can use `dir` to get a list of files in your current directory that end in ".txt":

```
files = dir('*.m');
filenames = {files.name};
```

And then loop over the files:

```
for ii = 1:length(filenames)
    filename = filenames{ii};

    % Read it into memory
    fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
    scanned_fields = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter','\n');
    fclose(fid);
    lines = scanned_fields{1};

    % Replace the asterisks with the desired text
    lines = strrep(lines, '******', '  0.00');

    % Overwrite the original file
    fid = fopen(filename, 'w');
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', lines{:});
    fclose(fid);

    % Go on to the next file
end
```

And of course, I would recommend creating a backup copy of this directory before running this, just in case something unexpected comes up.

Comment: Thanks, I think it would work perfectly. But when I included your code into my program, I got an error message for error using strrep:
Cell elements must be character arrays. Any easy fix?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I edited the answer to hopefully fix that; I had forgotten how textscan returns its output.

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted this answer. The only thing I changed is the to change fid = fopen(filename, 'w') to fid = fopen(filename, 'wt');